# Undefined method map on writing to a CSV file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to write lines from an input form to a CSV file from a string in a Rails model:

```
  def form_to_csv
    file = CSV.open('temp.csv', 'w+') do |csv|
      self.input_data.split("\n").each do |line|
        csv << line
      end
    end

    input_data_file = InputDataFile.new(file: file)
    self.input_data_file = input_data_file

  end
```

However I get the error:

> undefined method `map' for "...":String Did you mean? tap

Full error:

```
[FATAL] NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for "one\r":String Did you mean?  tap): 
[FATAL] app/models/job_request.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in form_to_csv' 
[FATAL] app/models/job_request.rb:111:in `each' 
[FATAL] app/models/job_request.rb:111:in `block in form_to_csv'
[FATAL] app/models/job_request.rb:110:in `form_to_csv' 
[FATAL] app/controllers/job_requests_controller.rb:21:in `create'
```

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: What is in `self.input_data`? Is it a string? Also you're missing an `end` tag. I think there should be another `end` after writing to the file so you can use variable `file` on line 7?

Comment: Where are you closing the `|csv|` clause?

Comment: self.input_data is a string yes

Comment: What is the whole stacktrace, you must get more info about the error than that one line.

Comment: posted full stacktrace

Comment: Ok, it mentions `job_request.rb` and `job_requests_controller.rb`, are you doing `map` there?

Comment: no, the error has nothing to do with the controller. MAP gets called through each iterator which breaks when CSV iterates over my string.

Comment: I also mentioned `job_request`, the error is not on the `each` line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132648/discussion-between-iceman-and-denis).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like input_data is a method that calls map on a string.

If you're not sure what's going on, you could add a `pry` or `byebug` in `app/models/job_request.rb:111`, then run the `form_to_csv` method so it pauses execution at the point of error.

I'll guess you would be surprised at the value/datatype of a certain variable ...